# How to assign last var

Tags: sas

I have a big data set such as

```
ca1   ca2   ca3   ca4   ca5   ca6   ca7   ca8   ca9
 1     1     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 1     0     0     8     8     8     8     8     8
 1     1     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8
 0     2     2     2     1     8     8     8     8
 0     0     0     1     2     1     8     8     8
```

I want to catch the var before the first var=8, but ignore 2, such as

```
ca1   ca2   ca3   ca4   ca5   ca6   ca7   ca8   ca9   new   type

 1     1     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     1     2
 1     0     0     8     8     8     8     8     8     0     3
 1     1     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     1     2
 0     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     8     0     1
 0     2     2     2     1     8     8     8     8     1     5
 0     0     0     1     2     1     8     8     8     1     6
```

new means new var
type means  which place

how can i do in the sas
thank a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays with a do loop like this.

```
data bidata2;
    set bigdata;
    array c ca1--ca9;
    do i = 1 to 9;
        if c(i)=8 then leave;
        else if c(i) NE 2 then type = i;
    end;
    if type NE . then new = c(type);
drop i;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what "ignore 2" means. If it doesn't really factor into things, then this is an interesting application of `whichn`, which identifies the first value in the 2nd through end arguments that is equal to the first argument.

```
data want;
  set have;
  array ca[9];
  type = whichn(8,of ca[*])-1;
  *what if it is all 8s - handle that somehow;
  new = ca[type];
run;
```

If it is a problem (and possible) for 2 to appear in this position, then you may need to use Pekka's version (which is probably more 'standard' but a bit slower if this is a really big dataset).